# Azure Cosmos MongoDB API: How to check for version?

Tags: jquery, version, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am connected to an Azure database through the MongDB API. What command can I run to check for the version I am using? I want to see the MongoDB API version and the Cosmos version.

Comment: I assume you mean that you are using Cosmos DB with the Mongo API?! Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos db mongo api only supports [2 versions protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36):`3.2` and `3.6`.You could choose the option when you create it:

[image]

You could check the version on the portal ui.

[image]

In addition, based on my test, [db.version()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.version/) command is not supported in the cosmos db mongo shell.You could check the supported features in the above document.